# Filtering a dictionary based on user supplied conditions

Tags: python, loops, input

Hello i have to set a code that creates a new lexikon based on data of an old lexikon and specific filters inserted by the user

1. gender(male or female)
2. age > 50

I have managed to set the code for the age barrier but I cannot find a way to combine it with the gender filter .Any recommendation?

```
old_lexikon = [{'GENDER' : 'MΑLE',
              'AGE' : 12,
              'WEIGHT' : 35,
              'HEIGHT' : 1.40},
             {'GENDER' : 'FEMALE',
              'AGE' : 19,
              'WEIGHT' : 65,
              'HEIGHT' : 1.70},
             {'GENDER' : 'MALE',
              'AGE' : 22,
              'WEIGHT' : 85,
              'HEIGHT' : 1.75} ,
             {'GENDER' : 'FEMALE',
              'AGE' : 24,
              'WEIGHT' : 55,
              'HEIGHT' : 1.50}]   
             

#this code from this point doesn't work properly 


new_lexikon = []
male_gender = 'MALE'
female_gender = 'FEMALE'
max_age = input('INSERT AGE: ')
gender = input('INSERT GENDER: ')
for entry in old_lexikon:
    if entry['AGE'] < int(max_age):
        new_lexikon.append(entry)
for entry in old_lexikon:
    if gender == male_gender:
        new_lexikon.append(entry)
        break
    if gender == female_gender:
        new_lexikon.append(entry)
        break
else:
    print('PLEASE INSERT CORRECT DATA:')
    print(new_lexikon)
```

Comment: And where is that code for age barrier?

Comment: You are defining your male_gender & female_gender as MALE or FEMALE, but the gender in your old_lexxicon is F or M  so it is never goi g to match. Besides that, your ifs inside the loop don't make any sense

Comment: my bad forgot to input the part with the age barrier

Answer (score 0):

Two things:

1. As pointed out by @nacho in the comments, your gender filter won't work because you're checking against `MALE` or `FEMALE` when your list of dictionaries only contains `M` / `F`
2. You're not combining the conditions with an `and`, so you get all the entries where either of the conditions is fulfilled and some of them multiple times.

What you want is something like this:

```py
new_lexikon = []

for entry in old_lexikon:
    if entry['AGE'] < int(max_age) and entry['GENDER'] == gender:
        new_lexikon.append(entry)
```

Comment: doesn't work:  1.getting empty list 2.MALE or FEMALE in input have no different output